# Filtering (searching) for two values (search criteria) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search

I'm trying to set up an application that takes two search criteria (Name and/or Tag).
I have the dynamic search set up for the search by name. But I can't filter further into the search for the tag name. How do I go about setting up a dynamic search for 2 values. In my case you should be able to search by `name && tag` or just `name` or just `tag`.

```
  const filteredResults = studentData.filter((student) => {
    const name = student.firstName + " " + student.lastName;
    return (
      name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
      student.tags.filter((tag) => {
        return tag.toLowerCase().includes(tagTerm.toLowerCase());
      })
    );
  });
```

This is what one entry of the api data looks like  this :

```
{
    city: "Fushë-Muhurr"
​​
    company: "Yadel"
​​
    email: "iorton0@imdb.com"
​​
    firstName: "Ingaberg"
​​
    grades: [ "78", "100", "92", … ]
​​
    id: "1"
​​
    lastName: "Orton"
​​
    pic: "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/voluptasdictablanditiis.jpg"
​​
    skill: "Oracle"
​​
    tags: [ "Tag1", "Tag2" ]
}
```

I'm linking my githubo repo here if anyone wants to take a look at it (It's a very small project):
https://github.com/EricPezzulo/HatchwaysFrontendAssessment

Comment: student.tags.filter is going to return always an array which is truthy, maybe you should add .length at the end of the filter in order to use it inside the condition?

Comment: do you need to match the full text or not necessary? you can leverage the regexp pattern to this.

Comment: @cute_programmer no its supposed to filter as you type (so if i type "F" all entries with "F" should populate and so on)

Comment: @FrancescoVattiato so your saying add `.length` like `student.tags.filter((tag) => { return tag.toLowerCase().includes(tagTerm.toLowerCase()); }).length`?

Comment: Yeah, actually I think you could also do ’student.tags.map(t=>t.toLowerCase()).includes(tagTerm.toLowerCase())’ instead of the filter

Comment: That worked halfway, it doesn't let me search for just the tag though

Comment: If I understand the last sentence in the question correctly: The search logic is flawed. You currently have an exclusive `||` that short circuits if the first test passes. ie. NAME || TAG - will match _just_ NAME or _just_ TAG but you have no code to match NAME _and_ TAG. You'll need a conditional for the two search logics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
const result = studentData.filter(({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    tags
}) => new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gui').test(`${firstName} ${lastName} ${tags.join(' ')}`));
```

Comment: for some reason that breaks something in my StudentContext.js file `Objects are not valid as a React child`

Comment: that error is not related to my answer. I think that error is when you return an invalid element to render.

Comment: Yes, its strange that it only happens why i try to use that code, I'm not sure why

Comment: So this actually works! I guess I was really tired last night and didn't realize I was rendering just {results}... not {results.map((i)-> {i.thing}}

Comment: glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you're trying to filter through both or just one of them.

The following code should resume what you have been asking for

```
const studentsArray = [{
    city: "Fushë-Muhurr",
    company: "Yadel",
    email: "iorton0@imdb.com",
    firstName: "Ingaberg",
    grades: [ "78", "100", "92"],
    id: "1",
    lastName: "Orton",
    pic: "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/voluptasdictablanditiis.jpg",
    skill: "Oracle",
    tags: [ "Tag1", "Tag2" ],
},
{
    city: "Fushë-Muhurr",
    company: "Yadel",
    email: "iorton0@imdb.com",
    firstName: "Ingaberg",
    grades: [ "78", "100", "92"],
    id: "1",
    lastName: "Orton",
    pic: "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/voluptasdictablanditiis.jpg",
    skill: "Oracle",
    tags: [ "Tag3", "Tag4" ],
}]

const searchTerm = ''
const tagTerm = ''

const filteredResults = studentsArray.filter((student) => {
    const name = student.firstName + ' ' +student.lastName;
    const nameIncludesSearchTerm = name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    const tagsIncludesTagTerm = student.tags.map(t=>t.toLowerCase()).includes(tagTerm.toLowerCase())
    const includesNameAndTag = nameIncludesSearchTerm && tagsIncludesTagTerm
    const includeNameOrTag = nameIncludesSearchTerm || tagsIncludesTagTerm
    return includesNameAndTag || includeNameOrTag;
  });

console.log({filteredResults})
```

Comment: I'm getting the same functionality as I had originally with that. Its still filtering for only the name and ignoring the tag filtering :/